# How do I map an X11 keysym to a Unicode character?

Tags: unicode, x11, keyboard-layout, xorg

X11 maps keycodes to keysyms and then maps keysyms to Unicode. What's a good way to retrieve keysym to Unicode mappings in a program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysym2ucs.c).

Comment: That's great! The same author has an easy to parse text file with those mappings which is what I used in my Python program.